# What is the maximum amount of fish you can have?

Tags: neko-atsume

Is there a maximum amount of fish you can have in Neko Atsume?

According to [chris_overseas on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/nekoatsume/comments/5hd948/is_there_a_max_amount_of_fish/daze5w6/?utm_content=permalink&utm_medium=front&utm_source=reddit&utm_name=nekoatsume), if there is a limit, it has to be somewhere over 100,000. Can the fish counter go up to 999,999?

[image: Over 100,000 fish]